# Django return count when date stored <= last 24 hours

Tags: python, django

I am noob, so this may be a simple question, but it has me stumped.

I am creating a test form so that each time the user creates a document, the date and time the document was created will be stored in the CreatedDocumentDetails model. I have not yet implemented this code yet, I am focusing on returning the count within the last 24 hours. I have inserted the values into the CreatedDocumentDetails model manually for the time being.

**The issue is that I want to make a count of the documents that have been created by the user in the last 24 hours.** I can return the total count of the users saved documents, but I am unsure how to write the now date & time field into the if statement to return the count of documents created in the last 24 hours.

I have the following model:

```
class CreatedDocumentDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_document_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user)
```

Here is the relevant views.py code:

```
def get_created_documents(user):
    created_documents = len(CreatedDocumentDetails.objects.filter(user=user))
    return created_documents
```

I am assuming that I somehow insert the now datetime field into the filter of the get_created_documents view code above.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Firstly, your existing code is very wrong. You should never do `len` on a queryset that you don't otherwise need to iterate: it fetches all the data, for no reason. Instead, use `count()`:

```
created_documents = CreatedDocumentDetails.objects.filter(user=user).count()
```

Secondly, since you already have one condition - on user - it shouldn't be too hard to add another. You just need a date comparison:

```
date_from = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
created_documents = CreatedDocumentDetails.objects.filter(
     user=user, created_document_timestamp__gte=date_from).count()
```

Also you might consider renaming your function and its variables: you're not actually getting the created documents, you're counting them, so `count_created_documents` or `get_created_documents_count` would be better names.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the advice and the date comparison code. This is very helpful. In my views.py I have added the from datetime import datetime, timedelta -  but I am getting the error: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'. Is this error to do with the import datetime?

Comment: @user4307426 Use either `import datetime`, or `datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)`. The `datetime` module contains a `datetime` object, so this can cause some confusion at first.