# django return the most recent date of a record

Tags: python, django

I am trying to return the most recent date from a number of records by a user.

When the user creates a document, the date created is stored in the CreatedDocumentDetails model.

I am unable to return the date of the most recently created document by the user.

I asked this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770837/django-return-count-when-date-stored-last-24-hours) that is kind of related to the issue.

Here is my model.py code:

```
class CreatedDocumentDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_document_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user)
```

Here is my views.py code:

```
def get_latest_created_document_date(user):
    ??
    return latest_created_document_date
```

I understand I have to pass the date in the filter of the get_latest_created_document_date view of the user, but after searching SO, Google and Django docs, I am still unable to figure this out on my own.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`order_by` QuerySet filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by), like so:

```
CreatedDocumentDetails.objects.order_by('-created_document_timestamp').first()
```

Since you are using a date field, you can also use the [`latest` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest) like so:

```
CreatedDocumentDetails.objects.latest('created_document_timestamp')
```

As catavaran states in the comments

> Note that if there is no records in table then `first()` will return `None` but `latest()` will raise `DoesNotExist` exception

To just get the datestamp, you can append the field to the end, as both queries will give a single object:

```
CreatedDocumentDetails.objects.order_by('-created_document_timestamp').first().created_document_timestamp
```

or

```
CreatedDocumentDetails.objects.latest('created_document_timestamp').created_document_timestamp
```

Comment: Note that if there is no records in table then `first()` will return `None` but `latest()` will raise `DoesNotExist` exception.

Comment: Lego Stormtroopr, your suggestion of CreatedDocumentDetails.objects.latest('created_document_timestamp') returns the user name. how do i return the most recent date the document was created?

Comment: It returns the whole object, I'm not sure how its giving the username. Eitherw ay I'll update the answer.

Comment: Lego Stormtroopr - thanks, I get it now! That really helped me.